# How to create a single request when submit multiple forms using a common single submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form which include 2 dropzone secrtions and a textboxes from and a single submti button on button submbit form submit but create three requests 2 dor dropzoen files and one form textboxes form but i need all this data in a single request. So how can we submti multiple form in a single request of array

Below is my JS Code

```
 <script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var file_after;
    var fileList = new Array;
    var i = 0;

    // Dropzone class:
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone", {

        {{--url: "{{route('dropzone-files')}}",--}}
        url: "{{route('case-submit')}}",
        acceptedFiles: '.stl',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        paramName: "file_before",
        params: {
            _token: "{{csrf_token()}}"
        },
    });

    var fileafterdropzone = new Dropzone("div#fileafterdropzone", {
        {{--url: "{{route('dropzone-files')}}",--}}
        url: "{{route('case-submit')}}",
        acceptedFiles: '.stl',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        parallelUploads: 10,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        paramName: "file_after",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        params: {
            _token: "{{csrf_token()}}"
        },
    });

</script>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function (e) {
        // Submit form data via Ajax
        $("#case-form").on('submit', function (e) {

            fileafterdropzone.processQueue();
            myDropzone.processQueue();

            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{route('case-submit')}}',
                // data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {

                    var files_before = Dropzone.forElement("div#mydropzone");
                    files_before.removeAllFiles();
                    var fiels_after = Dropzone.forElement("div#fileafterdropzone");
                    fiels_after.removeAllFiles();

                    $.notify("Case Registered Successfully", "success");

                },
                error: function (xhr, json, errorThrown) {

                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                    $.each(response.errors, function (key, value) {

                        $("#" + key + "_error").text(value[0]);
                        var element = document.getElementById(key + "_error");
                        element.classList.add('fa', 'fa-times-circle-o');
                        $("#" + key + "_error").css("color", "red");

                        $.notify(" There might be a problem case not registered", "error");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your explications are hard to understand, can you edit your message and make it clear and easy to read ? Be as precise as you can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each dropzone has its own post request, denoted by the `url` attribute on the dropzone creation and will want to send a request for each file.

What I would suggest doing is creating a new method to store your files (eg. to a `File` model). You could then return the `$file->id` back to the front-end using the dropzone success callback and append those file ids to the form.

Then on `submit` the form will have all the file ids of the files so you can associate them on the backend.